# Convert array of single-property JavaScript objects to array of key/value pairs

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of JavaScript dictionaries that look like

```
my_dictionary = [
    {"first_thing": "1"},
    {"second_thing": "2"}
]
```

, but which need to look like

```
my_dictionary = [
    {key: "first_thing", value: "1"},
    {key: "second_thing", value: "2"}
]
```

. Since there are so many of these dictionaries, I need a way to iterate through them and change all of the dictionaries so that they will have they `key` and `value` inside.

I have tried iterating through, and tried selecting them using something like `my_dictionary[0].key` as well as `my_dictionary[0][0]`, which I hoped would work, but I suppose that isn’t the way to do it.

Comment: ... Why not just `{ first_thing: 1, second_thing: 2}`? Why this array of single-property objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the transformation is happening in-element, i like using [].map() for this:

```
[{"first_thing": "1"}, {"second_thing":"2"}].map(function(o){
  var o2={};
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k){o2.key=k; o2.value=o[k];});
  return o2;
});

// == [{"key":"first_thing","value":"1"},{"key":"second_thing","value":"2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your dictionary and modify each element in place:

```
for (var index = 0; index < my_dictionary.length; index++) {
    var element = my_dictionary[index],
        key, value;

    // Grab the initial element
    for (var tempKey in element) {
        if (element.hasOwnProperty(tempKey)) {
            key = tempKey;
            value = element[tempKey];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Reset the element
    element = { "key": key, "value": value };
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
 var result = [];
 var my_dictionary = [{"first_thing": "1"}, {"second_thing":"2"}];
 $.each(my_dictionary, function(index, element) {
     $.each(element, function(key, value) {
         result.push({"key" : key, "value" : value});
     });
 });
```

Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/36o170w9/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `for..in`

No side effects

```
var dict_in = [{"first_thing": "1"}, {"second_thing": "2"}];

var dict_out = (function (arr) {
    var d = [], i, k;
    d.length = arr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        for (k in arr[i]) {
            d[i] = {'key': k, 'value': arr[i][k]};
            break;
        }
    return d;
}(dict_in));

dict_out; // [{key: "first_thing", value: "1"}, {key: "second_thing", value: "2"}]
```

Side effects

```
var dict_in = [{"first_thing": "1"}, {"second_thing": "2"}];

(function (arr) {
    var i, k, v;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        for (k in arr[i]) {
            v = arr[i][k];
            delete arr[i][k];
            arr[i].key = k;
            arr[i].value = v;
            break;
        }
    return arr;
}(dict_in)); // [{key: "first_thing", value: "1"}, {key: "second_thing", value: "2"}]
```